# reading text from file in C

Tags: c, file

I am trying read a text from file in C but I am getting nothing in command prompt.Here my code is,please help me ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    FILE *file=NULL;
    file = fopen("C:\\Users\\ylmzt_000\\Desktop\\Yeni klasör\\deneme.txt", "r");

    if(file != NULL)
    {
        printf("----------------\n");
        printf("content\n");
        printf("-----------------\n");

        int ch;
        while((ch=fgetc(file)) != EOF)
        {
            putchar(ch);
        }
        printf("\n");
        fclose(file);
    }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add a `else` to `if(file != NULL)` which prints a message if the file fails to open. Then you can see the problem.

Comment: Do the lines "-----------------" appear?

Answer (score 2):

If `fopen()` returns NULL, an error occured. Construct an `else` part which may contain

fprintf(stderr, "cannot open '%s' (%s)\n", fn, strerror(errno));

where `fn` contains your filename.

Also see http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen for further hints.

Answer (score 0):

There is no obvious problem in your code.  The problem may be related to the fact that the filename contains non-ASCII characters:

```
C:\\Users\\ylmzt_000\\Desktop\\Yeni klasör\\deneme.txt
```

Try renaming the directory with only ASCII characters.

Comment: if you mean "ylmzt_000" ,for  every character in it there is an ASCII code , I checked .Also tried putting an "else" but it did not work,

Comment: No, I mean `Yeni klasör`.  `ö` is not an ASCII character.

Comment: What about `Yeni klasör` ?

Comment: I changed it to "sample " but still getting nothing

Comment: Did you also add an `else` branch to the `if` to produce an error message ?

Comment: Perhaps your file doesn't exist or it's empty!

Comment: Even if the files was empty, some output would be visible.  The error message is needed to check whether `fopen` succeeded or not.

Comment: Yes I added an else branch to the if to produce an error message.Also checked file.It exists and it is not empty."printf" functions does not printing anything.

Comment: Edit your question, post the modified code and the actual output you get.